# PostgreSQL - pg_monitor role

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, permissions

I have problem - probably with postgres permissions. I created a user and granted role to him:

```
CREATE USER test PASSWORD 'abc';
GRANT pg_monitor TO test;
```

Next I want to login as test user and run query:

```
select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;
```

But unfortunately user does not have sufficient permissions and i can't see some info from this select (for example i can't see relid info)

Sample output:

```
 pid  |   datid   |     datname      | relid | phase | heap_blks_total | heap_blks_scanned | heap_blks_vacuumed | index_vacuum_count | max_dead_tuples | num_dead_tuples
-------+-----------+------------------+-------+-------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------
 1241 | 213123214 | database1 |       |       |                 |                   |                    |                    |                 |
```

PS. I have PostgreSQL 12.2

Comment: Your output shows ```pid``` so was that run by different user?

Comment: It is autovacuum process.

Comment: @Matix123 that doesn't answer his question.

Comment: To clarify, who ran the ```select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;``` query that produced the output that shows a ```pid```?

Comment: User test created by "CREATE USER test PASSWORD 'abc';" with privileges "GRANT pg_monitor TO test;"

Answer (score 1):

You say you can't see the pid, but the example you show is clearly showing the pid.  I assume it the other 8 columns, starting with "relid", that you can't see.

This works for me.  When pg_monitor is granted and a vacuum is running, I see data in all columns, and when it not granted I see the final 8 columns being NULL.

This looks like some kind of user error, like you are connecting as the wrong user, or to the wrong server, or the GRANT is not actually being executed.

Comment: Yes, you are right - i can't see the last 8 columns. I use "test" user - test user has "pg_monitor" role

Comment: So @jjanes do you have any ideas why i still can't see the last 8 columns ?

Comment: When you have logged in as "test" in psql, run `\du` to make sure the permissions are what you think they are.

Comment: Yes, it looks fine:
test   |            | {pg_monitor}

Comment: @Matix123   I'm stumped.  Can you reproduce this from a completely clean initdb with default settings for postgresql.conf and showing the CREATE DATABASE and any GRANTS you had done (other than the own already shown)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.When i create clean initdb with default settings for postgresql.conf it works great. And this is problem - i don't know what is the problem. This is the production db and i can't create completely new environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after postgresql was migrated from 14 to 15 : the user in charge of monitoring had no permission to view pg_stat_* "superuser" columns.

For some reason my monitoring user had a "no inheritance" attribute :

```
 => \du centreon
               List of roles
 Role name |   Attributes   |  Member of   
-----------+----------------+--------------
 centreon  | No inheritance | {pg_monitor}
```

The problem was solved by :

```
=# alter user centreon with inherit;
ALTER ROLE
=# \du centreon
             List of roles
 Role name | Attributes |  Member of   
-----------+------------+--------------
 centreon  |            | {pg_monitor}
```